# How to combine react-router-dom's setSearchParams with route that has a param in a way that allows correct back button usage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a set of routes that look like this:

```
{
    path: '/things',
    element: <MainLayout />,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'search',
            element: <MainSearch />,
        },
        {
            path: 'search/:thingId',
            element: <ThingLayout />,
        },
        {
            path: '',
            element: <Navigate to="search" replace />,
        },
    ],
},
```

Wherein the idea is you search for something on MainSearch, are given results, click it, and are brought to a page `/things/search/:thingId` for that Thing.

However, ThingLayout has a tab paradigm happening too, which is set by search params, and the user clicking tabs within that component.

*ThingLayout.tsx*

```
import { useParams, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ThingLayout = () => {
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const activeTab = searchParams.get('tab');

    // When the user first comes here from general search route, 
    // set the default tab
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!activeTab) {
            setSearchParams({ tab: DEFAULT_TAB });
        }
    }, []);

// ...
}
```

My trouble is, I need (I believe) the generalized `/search/:thingId` route so that all my various `/search/:thingId?tab=someTab` routes resolve to this component, which then has code to check which tab is set via `searchParams` and then render the proper child component, but if a user presses the back button, the URL changes to `/search/:thingId` and then immediately back to `/search/:thingId?tab=defaultTab`. I tried using `navigate` rather than `setSearchParams` to change the URL:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    navigate(`?tab=${DEFAULT_INVENTORY_PARTS_TAB}`)
```

But I had the same issue: when coming from search, first the URL would be `/search/:thingId`, then it would become `?tab=defaultTab`.

I've searched through the react router docs, as well as looked at a great many stackoverflow questions, and I'm thinking now maybe I just am following a bad pattern? Is my method of tab navigation compatible with the "right" way to use React Router? How can I combine the general `:id` route with my manipulated `searchParams` route?

My react router version is `"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setSearchParams` works similar to the `navigate` function but only for the URL queryString. It takes an options object that is the same type argument as `navigate`.

> ```
> declare function useSearchParams(
>   defaultInit?: URLSearchParamsInit
> ): [URLSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams];
>
> type ParamKeyValuePair = [string, string];
>
> type URLSearchParamsInit =
>   | string
>   | ParamKeyValuePair[]
>   | Record<string, string | string[]>
>   | URLSearchParams;
>
> type SetURLSearchParams = (
>   nextInit?: URLSearchParamsInit,
>   navigateOpts?: : { replace?: boolean; state?: any }
> ) => void;
> ```

Pass a `navigateOpts` object that sets the navigation type to be a redirect.

```
import { useParams, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ThingLayout = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const activeTab = searchParams.get('tab');

  // When the user first comes here from general search route, 
  // set the default tab
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!activeTab) {
      searchParams.set("tab", DEFAULT_TAB);
      setSearchParams(searchParams, { replace: true });
    }
  }, []);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: this technically answers my question more directly, insomuch as it's how to use setSearchParams, whereas my solution uses a different function entirely to accomplish my goals, so i'm accepting it

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the `navigate` function provided by `react-router-dom`'s `useNavigate` hook, which has a `replace` parameter that can be passed to it, to replace the current item in history.

So my code that checks to see if there is a tab selected, and if not, sets the search parameter, now `navigate`s to the URL with the proper search parameter set, rather than setting the search parameter directly and only.

```
import { useParams, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ThingLayout = () => {
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const activeTab = searchParams.get('tab');

    // When the user first comes here from general search route, 
    // set the default tab
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!activeTab) {
            setSearchParams({ tab: DEFAULT_TAB });
        }
    }, []);

// ...
}
```

becomes

```
import { useSearchParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ThingLayout = () => {
    const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const activeTab = searchParams.get('tab');

    // When the user first comes here from general search route, 
    // set the default tab
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!activeTab) {
            navigate(`?tab=${DEFAULT_TAB}`, {replace: true});
        }
    }, []);

// ...
}
```